# React/Bootstrap: How to get drop down menu to be rendered on top of everything?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I am trying to have a Bootstrap dropdown menu when a button is clicked. I have a component structure like this:

```
<>
   <div className='1'>
      <navbar/>

      <div>
         <homepage/>
      </div>
   </div>
</>
```

The button is inside the `<navbar>` component, which lives at the top of the page. When the button is clicked, the component's state is changed, and another component is rendered (this component contains all the items in the drop down menu).

When I click the button, the drop down items show up - but, they are shown to the side of the button and are squished inside the `<div>` containing the `<navbar>` component (classname=1). I want the dropdown menu to be on top of everything, including the content in the `<homepage>` component (sort of overlayed on top).

How can I make this happen?

Edit:

For now, I am just using simple drop downs, like from: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Comment: I do not get the problem in total - are there other elements in front of the dropdown, or what do you mean? In that case, you should have a look at the css `z-index` property. Setting `z-index: -1;` will always render that element at the very front.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a fixed or sticky header, you can position it on top of everything in pure CSS with `position: fixed;` The main takeaway in React is 'conditional rendering,' which means we can render and re-render a component dynamically based upon the truthy or falsy value of a variable; see below how it works with AND operator `{showDropdown && <DropdownMenu />}`

As for the dropdown menu logic, this design pattern can be accomplished with this code

App.jsx:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './App.css';

function App() {

  function Navbar() {
    const [showDropdown, setShowDropdown] = useState(false);
  
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
      setShowDropdown(!showDropdown);
    };
  
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
        <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>Show Dropdown</button>
        {showDropdown && <DropdownMenu />}
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  function DropdownMenu() {
    return (
      <div className="dropdown-menu">
        <p>Dropdown 1</p>
        <p>Dropdown 2</p>
        <p>Dropdown 3</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  function Homepage() {
    return (
      <div className="homepage">
        {/* Content of the homepage component */}
        <h1>Homepage</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container-1">
        <Navbar />
        <div>
          <Homepage />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css:

```
.container-1 {
  position: relative;
}

.navbar {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot. After implementing your solution, I am now getting the error of the dropdown menu going off of the side of the page and creating a horizontal scroll bar.

How can I ensure that the menu stays on the main page?

Comment: @user545642 What do you mean exactly 'going off of the side of the page'? It sounds like the horizontal scrollbar is caused by the 'position' property being fixed, sticky, or absolute. Try position: relative. If it persists, then it could be the parent element's CSS is off, maybe wrong width, margin, or misuse of flexbox or grid.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried `z-index`?
I recommend to use custom style to achieve that.